# How do I iterate a list over different csv files?

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to create 3 new csv files (one for each element in itemTypes) and place the out in each file. This is the code I have so far and I'm stuck:

```
itemTypes = ['phone','tower','laptop']
x = range(len(itemTypes)) 
for y in x:
    with open('test' + str(y) + '.csv', 'w+', newline='') as file4:
        test_writer = csv.writer(file4, delimiter=',')
        for row, entry in inventory.items():
            entry.insert(0, row)
            for line in entry:
                if itemTypes[y] in line:
                    del entry[2]
                    print(entry)
                    test_writer.writerow(entry)
```

I am looking for a way to open and write in x amount of files depending on how many items the user puts in itemTypes. In this case, it's 3 but I want to allow it to fit any number. The output I have is only correct for [test0.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXQvP.jpg). But [test1.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnsFS.jpg) and [test2.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLPJB.jpg) have jumbled entries and I can't tell why.

The desired output is that each item should have its own file, and in the file it each column should have the item ID, manufacturer name, price, service date, and list if it is damaged, order by ID.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @Dharman It wont let me delete, but if I dont ill get in trouble

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
itemTypes = ['phone','tower','laptop']
for item_type in itemTypes:
    with open(f'{item_type}.csv', 'w+', newline='') as file4:
        test_writer = csv.writer(file4, delimiter=',')
        for row, entry in inventory.items():
            entry.insert(0, row)
            for line in entry:
                if itemTypes[0] in line:
                    del entry[2]
                    print(entry)
                    test_writer.writerow(entry)
```

Comment: Its the same issue again, the phone.csv was printed correctly but tower.csv and laptop.csv were both blank

Comment: @PythonStudent Then it has to do with the code snippet inside with with block. Without seeing `inventory`, can't fix it. I just fixed automatically creating multiple csv files.

Comment: This is only a small portion of the project, `inventory` is quite large. I made a justpast.it if you want to take a look at it. justpaste.it/StackOverflow99

Comment: @PythonStudent This is pretty neat issue, You need to check which values in `inventory` have 'Samsung', 'Apple', 'Lenovo' etc in them and categorize them accordingly whether to send in `phone.csv` or `tower.csv` or `laptop.csv`. But again the structure of the values in that dict isn't consistent. The two inner for loops need lots of changes.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Ive changed up my question a bit if its more understanding.